# QueryString malformed after URLDecode

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I'm trying to pass in a Base64 string into a C#.Net web application via the QueryString. When the string arrives the "+" (plus) sign is being replaced by a space. It appears that the automatic URLDecode process is doing this. I have no control over what is being passed via the QueryString. Is there any way to handle this server side?

Example:

```
http://localhost:3399/Base64.aspx?VLTrap=VkxUcmFwIHNldCB0byAiRkRTQT8+PE0iIHBsdXMgb3IgbWludXMgNSBwZXJjZW50Lg==
```

Produces:

```
VkxUcmFwIHNldCB0byAiRkRTQT8 PE0iIHBsdXMgb3IgbWludXMgNSBwZXJjZW50Lg==
```

People have suggested URLEncoding the querystring:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(yourString)
```

I can't do that as I have no control over the calling routine (which is working fine with other languages).

There was also the suggestion of replacing spaces with a plus sign:

```
Request.QueryString["VLTrap"].Replace(" ", "+");
```

I had though of this but my concern with it, and I should have mentioned this to start, is that I don't know what *other* characters might be malformed in addition to the plus sign.

***My main goal is to intercept the QueryString before it is run through the decoder.***

To this end I tried looking at Request.QueryString.toString() but this contained the same malformed information. Is there any way to look at the raw QueryString *before* it is URLDecoded?

After further testing it appears that .Net expects everything coming in from the QuerString to be URL encoded but the browser does not automatically URL encode GET requests.

Comment: OK, so now I'm completely at loss at how SO works. The question explicitly states that  there's no way to change what's passed into the QueryString, but all correct answers (i.e., replace space with plus before base64-decoding) have been voted down. Go figure...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could manually replace the value (`argument.Replace(' ', '+')`) or consult the `HttpRequest.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"]` (even better the HttpRequest.Url.Query) and parse it yourself.

You should however try to solve the problem where the URL is given; a plus sign needs to get encoded as "%2B" in the URL because a plus otherwise represents a space.

If you don't control the inbound URLs, the first option would be preferred as you avoid the most errors this way.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use Uri.EscapeDataString/Uri.UnescapeDataString.

Answer (score 14):

The suggested solution:

```
Request.QueryString["VLTrap"].Replace(" ", "+");
```

Should work just fine.  As for your concern:

> I had though of this but my concern with it, and I should have mentioned this to start, is that I don't know what other characters might be malformed in addition to the plus sign.

This is easy to alleviate by [reading about base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).  The only non alphanumeric characters that are legal in modern base64 are "/", "+" and "=" (which is only used for padding).

Of those, "+" is the only one that has special meaning as an escaped representation in URLs.  While the other two have special meaning in URLs (path delimiter and query string separator), they shouldn't pose a problem.

So I think you should be OK.

Answer (score 4):

I'm having this exact same issue except I have control over my URL. Even with `Server.URLDecode` and `Server.URLEncode` it doesn't convert it back to a `+` sign, even though my query string looks as follows:

```
http://localhost/childapp/default.aspx?TokenID=0XU%2fKUTLau%2bnSWR7%2b5Z7DbZrhKZMyeqStyTPonw1OdI%3d
```

When I perform the following.

```
string tokenID = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["TokenID"]);
```

it still does not convert the `%2b` back into a `+` sign.  Instead I have to do the following:

```
string tokenID = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["TokenID"]);
tokenID = tokenID.Replace(" ", "+");
```

Then it works correctly.  Really odd.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. Looks like `Request.QueryString["TokenID"]` returns already URLdecoded string. By passing it to Server.UrlDecode you doing urldecoding twice.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with a parameter that contains Base64 value and when it comes with '+'.
Only Request.QueryString["VLTrap"].Replace(" ", "+"); worked fine for me;
no UrlEncode or other encoding helping because even if you show encoded link on page yourself with '+' encoded as a '%2b' then it's browser that changes it to '+' at first when it showen and when you click it then browser changes it to empty space. So no way to control it as original poster says even if you show links yourself. The same thing with such links even in html emails.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(yourString)` it will ignore the `+`.  This method should only be used in cases like yours where when the string was encoded using some sort of legacy approach either on the client or server.

See this blog post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yangxind/archive/2006/11/09/don-t-use-net-system-uri-unescapedatastring-in-url-decoding.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you URLEncode the string before adding it to the URL you will not have any of those problems (the automatic URLDecode will return it to the original state).

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously you should have the Base64 string URLEncoded before sending it to the server.
If you cannot accomplish that, I would suggest simply replacing any embedded spaces back to +; since b64 strings are not suposed to have spaces, its a legitimate tactic...

Comment: "Well, obviously you should have the Base64 string URLEncoded before sending it to the server"....he said he has no control over that though.

Comment: Hence the obviously... and the alternative afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(yourString)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick hack you could replace space with plus character before base64-decoding.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means a C# developer but it looks like you need to url ENCODE your Base64 string before sending it as a url.

Comment: He doesn't have control of the URL - see his question.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just assume a space is a + and replace it?

```
Request.QueryString["VLTrap"].Replace(" ", "+");
```

;)