# ASP.NET MVC - creating and handling with URLs with Greater Than and Less Than characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, urlencode, actionlink

Consider a link to a page for a user's profile. A page is creating that URL like this:

```
//Model.Name has value "<bad guy>"
Html.ActionLink("foo, "ViewUser", new { id=5, title=Url.Encode(Model.Name) })
```

The actual outcome was

```
http://mysite/Users/5/%253cbad%2guy%253e
```

When navigating to that URL, the server generates a `HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.`

The problem surfaces when testing out 'interesting' user inputs with `<` and `>`, but anything could come from the user, and therefore be put in a URL by way of `Model.Name`.

**Question:**
Given that the `Model.Name` may contain Unicode characters, or characters otherwise illegal in URLs:

- what's the best way to strip out illegal characters, or otherwise encode them?
- should the user's input be sanitized BEFORE being saved to the database, thereby preventing the encoding attempt above?
- which characters should be sanitized (i.e. not allowed) when thinking of having that string be part of a URL?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use base 64 encoding on any parameters that might contain the special characters.

See here for an example:

**Allowing special characters in ASP.Net MVC URL parameters**
http://gathadams.com/2009/01/06/allowing-special-characters-forward-slash-hash-asterisk-etc-in-aspnet-mvc-urls/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228701/code-for-decoding-encoding-a-modified-base64-url for a good example on how to use base 64 encoding...and decoding