# What kind of encoding is neccessary for cookies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, encoding

For `cookie` what kind of `encoding` should be performed (converting a byte array to text) ?

```
Base64 ?
UrlEncode ?
...
```

Comment: I mean if I'm going to convert a byte array to string, is base64 enough for cookies or UrlEncoding should be done too ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need any encoding. To prevent user tampering, the simplest solution is to use [sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) (which typically uses `ASP.NET_SessionId` behind the scenes), rather than making custom cookies.

<s>EDIT: If you really need to store an arbitrary byte array, base 64 will work.  But you should explain why you want to do this.</s>

Comment: I just need to transfer some data from one server to another (both on subdomains of the same domain). I need to be sure I'm not gonna use invalid characters in cookie text.

Comment: @Xaqron, transferring it via cookies could be dangerous, because the user can tamper with it.

Comment: @ Mathew: I encrypt it and tamper-proof it with hash. That's why I need to know is any encoding is needed or not.

Comment: Base 64 uses characters that are not safe for cookies or URL's.

Comment: @NeilWhitaker, thanks.  You're right, the = sign could be a problem (it has meanings in both base64 and cookies).  I've struck that line.

Answer (score 0):

I personally will MD5 encode an ID and store just about everything in a DB or if i can change the db use a GUID instead of a incrementing ID

Answer (score 0):

Base64-encoded strings are not valid for URLs or cookies. There are a number of variations on base64 encoding that avoid the forbidden characters. In .NET, you can use HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode() and .UrlTokenDecode().

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789179/24315