# Asp.Net URL Encoding Broken

Tags: asp.net, url, .net-2.0

I'm encrypting values and adding them to the URL. My problem though is that after I run it through HttpUtility.URLEncode I sometimes come up with bad URLs. I get stuff like

```
www.mysite.com/page.aspx?id=+jdghogjhior==
```

I think the it's the leading plus that's giving me trouble. Any ideas? What do you guys do?

Similar problems to what this guy talks about:
[Server.UrlEncode vs. HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602642/server-urlencode-vs-httputility-urlencode/1148326#1148326)

Comment: Please post your code, what the input to `Encode` is and what you expect as result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the thing you're encoding by chance already base64 encoded?

If so you'll need to use a ["modified" base64 which is compatible with URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications):

> ... a modified Base64 for URL variant exists, where no padding '=' will be used, and the '+' and '/' characters of standard Base64 are respectively replaced by '-' and '_'

See [Code for decoding/encoding a modified base64 URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228701/code-for-decoding-encoding-a-modified-base64-url) for example.

Comment: yup, that was it. I was double encoding / decoding

Answer (score 1):

You can try to take an encrypted string, convert it to base64 string and send it via url. When you receive it, decode from base64 and decrypt it.

Encoding:

```
byte[] bt = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("5dnjnbf&&#jnb3=+");
string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bt);
```

Decode:

```
byte[] bt = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
string s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the + is the only problem, so habitualy I replace it with something else that I know won't be in the query like space (%20)

But in somme case you need spaces

so have you try : Uri.EscapeDataString

Like the link you have posted ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it brought the id across correctly:

```
<a href='Page.aspx?ID=
    <%=server.urlencode(server.htmlencode("+jdghogjhior==")) %>'>Click here</a>
```

Comment: So, really, htmlEncoding it, then urlEncoding it did the trick.