# "Login Failure" using LinkedIn OAuth in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linkedin-api

I am taking a look at the default OAuth implementation that comes with asp.net mvc 4. It definitely is impressive, as all i had to do was add this line in AuthConfig.cs:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterLinkedInClient("_key_", "_secret_");
```

enabling above, did offer up the LinkedIn link to login. I was prompted for password once, but after entering it i got:

> "Login Failure. Unsuccessful login with service."

, and have been getting this ever since w/out ever being prompted for password again.

It is not clear to me if this is due to initial bad credentials i entered, or something with the way i set up the key.

Also, i don't see the actual controller code anywhere within my app, so even if my login worked, it is not clear how i could obtain information from linked in.. i.e. history.

it is nice how easy this integration was, but I am leaning towards a [more manual implementation of this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438511/login-with-linkedin)

however i can't help but wonder that above implementation probably also works.

**UPDATE**

i've traced the problem to be this call:

```
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl) {
    return new ExternalLoginResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
}
```

callback comes back with ***"401 Unauthorized"***.. even though the credentials are correct. from what i can gather in other posts, this may be due to incorrectly formed headers by OAuth library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and it would appear that this is a bug.

See "Paul Roa" comments on this post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx?PageIndex=2

and then his solution (which works for me), here:

http://blog.mrroa.com/post/30454808112/asp-net-custom-linkedin-oauth-provider

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I updated all OAuth packages using NuGet, and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that OAuth was shipped in vs2012 with a bug. Here is the tutorial that explains why the error. http://www.devcurry.com/2013/01/connect-to-linkedin-using-oauth-in.html

I had to also update Nuget in order to get the DotNetOpenAuth.Core package to update. Once updated, it worked as expected. Hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like bad credentials, it worked fine for me. Sadly the template does not allow changing passwords or deleting accounts, but you could remove the LinkedIn connection and then create a new account from your LinkedIn login to try again.

As for the implementation they use and extending it I haven't gotten around to looking into that yet. Plan to do so though since I'm also thinking about using it if it looks good.