# Possible values we can extracted from "LinkedIn Authentication through OAuth"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, oauth, linkedin-api

I am using MVC 4.0 where i can pass the consumer key and consumer secret in `AuthConfig.cs` file.

> What are all the possible values that i can extract from "Login with
>   LinkedIn" Extract Data?

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770971/login-failure-using-linkedin-oauth-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: that link doesn't answer my question at all.