# image corrupted when Uploading to ftp using ftpwebrequest

Tags: c#, ftp

I used this code to upload image to ftp. but image is corrupted.
image im trying to upload is a `Base64` string.i converted to stream and passed it to UpLoadImage.

```
 public static void UpLoadImage(Stream image, string target)
   {
    FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.examp.com/images/" + target);
    req.UseBinary = true;
    req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserNm", "PassWd");
    StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(image);
    byte[] fileData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rdr.ReadToEnd());
    rdr.Close();
    req.ContentLength = fileData.Length;
    Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    reqStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
    reqStream.Close();
}
```

Instead of:

> StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(image);
>       byte[] fileData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rdr.ReadToEnd());
>       rdr.Close();

if i use  `byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(image);`
it gives me a error, filename is to more the 260 character.

Please can someone help to solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a Stream to read binary files, not a StreamReader. StreamReader is designed to read text files only.

and about error [Maximum Path Length Limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Maximum Path Length Limitation In the Windows API (with some
>   exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length
>   for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. A local
>   path is structured in the following order: drive letter, colon,
>   backslash, name components separated by backslashes, and a terminating
>   null character. For example, the maximum path on drive D is "D:\some
>   256-character path string" where "" represents the invisible
>   terminating null character for the current system codepage. (The
>   characters < > are used here for visual clarity and cannot be part of
>   a valid path string.)

path limition:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pathtoolongexception.aspx

**Edited**

I write a simple one:
Convert image to b64 and back

```
//Convert image to b64
            string path = @"E:\Documents and Settings\Ali\Desktop\original.png";
            Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
            byte[] arr;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                arr = ms.ToArray();
            }
            String b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(arr);//result:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEA...
            //Get image bytes
            byte[] originalimage= Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
```

send b64 to your function and convert it back `byte[] originalimage= Convert.FromBase64String(b64);`

Comment: byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(image) requires a string as parameter.

Comment: @user2226345:File.ReadAllBytes("address of your image"),i think your path is >260 charachter

Comment: when i pass a base64 string to File.ReadAllBytes(image) it shows an error that the filename or path is to long(has more than 260 character)

Comment: your path is >260 character

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228701/code-for-decoding-encoding-a-modified-base64-url

Comment: image name encoded with Base64 string?could you add part of code?

Comment: public string Test(String url1)
        {
             byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(url1);
             MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
             UpLoadImage(url1,"DSdiagnosis.jpg");

Comment: that is the funtion which calls UpLoadImage(). where url1 is canvas image which being accessed using webservice.

Comment: you are encode your URL like this: `byte[] url = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("c:\\original.png");` so after you send stream address to upload function get original URL again with `File.ReadAllBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(url));`

Comment: this is the content of image image= "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAAAAAAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcHBw8LCwkMEQ8SEhEPERETFhwXExQaFRERGCEYGh0dHx8fExciJCIeJBweHx7/2wBDAQUFBQcGBw4ICA4eFBEUHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh7/wAARCADIA5MDASIAAhEBA...

Comment: Sorry there is a change in the code --> public string Test(String url1) { byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(url1); MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray); UpLoadImage(stream,"DSdiagnosis.jpg");

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(url)); to use this parameter should be a byte[].so when i convert url to byte[] and pass,it gives the same error PathTooLong.

Comment: `byte[] originalimage= Convert.FromBase64String(b64);`this line is the same as `File.ReadAllBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(url));` instead od using `File.ReadAllBytes` use my code

Comment: the error has changed to :The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.

Answer (score 2):

Like a comment say
use

```
byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
```

for all file that are not text file.

like that:

```
private void FTPUPLOAD(string imgPath)
        {
            FTPDelete(img);
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(BaseUrl +Path.GetFileName(imgPath));
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Account, Password);

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
             //THIS IS THE CODE
            byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(imgPath);

 Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            response.Close();
        }
```