# Byte[]String to String in C#

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net, byte

I have the byte Array String like this that it's encoded by Base64 method on android like this one

```
return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

so I've sened it to my web api an I've Got Something like This (this is my byte array)

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAGACAIAAABUQk3oAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U_gAAAgAElEQVR4 nOy925IkSZIddo6aR9ZcdoWEQIR4Af__Wyh4Iz-AT5AVPhAQrIC705VhevigFzOPiKrO7unZ7axx nZ6sCA93c3NzM70cvRj_6f_9vwEAhqT-AECAzh--T9ouJkSAeTm3FsTzXb5Fnlc_t_26nw7unSQU p3U3XtJqR5D4gcfUywYfjwg6H3u6JNv5yFA808urPviavj8gF30m-h__7Z_-r__r__yn__pf39_f 
>   .....................................
>   PRqEJ9oLFmsrpX1vhBXq82y1knRVUKFRwRwDgy8EiWTGfD5ZvpEz2dB54fIv8sgaY1oHz-e0M_l0 Fa1ym728AKyom8xstoaVBhv0YolD1jkAInXMwVi9JEXcfUqgHTSZz7oIYwzjGHYjRiXJOX2XLDkE H1uv5MqlbdqjV4KD20eaW6rv4-HT0ePbQicqOzC7_wsSX-sS9mzikrwvurHr_rux9-h8ijOejjxc uwmAl8bX6wf5G_HTj7D7j9z6I4Lkor9Tan-mmQGTUWYgImFgoEnOrPsQVzQgJCnD8yFxAyw21d2E SB5TJNFyNSAA1HbuJmNq9ff_tbF3Vth9OwLye3YKpT12S53VfH5wVCSP3JvZcGvq8

also I've use an other method on the client side that it responed me like this one

> ������JFIF����������������C������C�������"��������������������������
>       �����������}��!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�
>       %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
>       ���������w��!1AQaq"2�B����  #3R�br�
>       $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz������������������������������������������������������������������W5���K4(�ڇ�R+$Sk�W��yd��yŬ,��oR����#-�    9,�ӗb'Nx�sJ<�Jo�ZsM�����i���a�'MΪ���֪)����q�j�����:�$[�2��dqPp`����z�����<?�$+���
>       a����rMz|֝t�b�\��
>       C
>   ��$.I��Q�Q�Q��3��S�k�;w�ɽ�6��<7��թR�Qvs��*��z���+�ngtӊ,|�<`��}ON�=O�\��3�Y4�q��ipy��m��$����29�q���y9䁀x�=�䍣>)�O_6��d:,fISq!_ϕQ�'������$��k�*�IW��;/ek��N�륚�e���E�\%��%yUR��uի���S�K�[��4~`f;\�ݹ��*��Ǯy����k>�4

which is correct ?

how do i convert it to the byte[]?

I've find these two method one work but the file is damaged and an other one got an exeption

method 1 :

```
 static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }
```

method 2 (exeption):

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                         .ToArray();
    }
```

so what Shall i do ??

Comment: Not sure how code shown relates to your data... If you send base64 (even with modified alphabet) I'd expect some sort of base64 decoding code for other end... Something closer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228701/code-for-decoding-encoding-a-modified-base64-url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you have: `Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s);`

Comment: Which obviously not going to work with non-default set of characters used by OP.