# Base64 url safe encoding and decoding between Android and C#

Tags: c#, android, base64, decode, encode

In my android application, I am using `java.util.Base64` encoding and decoding with the flags `URL_SAFE` and `NO_WRAP`.

However, when I try to decode it in my C# application using `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode`, I am getting back `null`. At this state, my encoded string cannot also be decoded on the Android application.

What am I missing out on? Doesn't the `URL_SAFE` flag ensure that the Base64 string has no `+`, `/` and any extra padding? How come `UrlTokenEncode` is not accepting the Base64 value?

[I was using this post as reference, for anyone who is interested.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228701/code-for-decoding-encoding-a-modified-base64-url/1789179#1789179)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UrlTokenEncode` returned `null` because I was passing a `string` and not a `UrlToken`.

Sticking to the `URL_SAFE` and `NO_WRAP` Base64 flags for both encoding/decoding in Android, I managed to change my C# application to decode/encode in a url_safe manner.

```
    public string UrlEncode(string str)
    {
        if (str == null || str == "")
        {
            return null;
        }

        byte[] bytesToEncode = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
        String returnVal = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytesToEncode);

        return returnVal.TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
    }

    public string UrlDecode(string str)
    {
        if (str == null || str == "")
        {
            return null;
        }

        str.Replace('-', '+');
        str.Replace('_', '/');

        int paddings = str.Length % 4;
        if (paddings > 0)
        {
            str += new string('=', 4 - paddings);
        }

        byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(str);
        string returnVal = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);
        return returnVal;
    }
```

Comment: Useful thanks. 
But isn't there a C# version of url_safe encoding that does not require us to manually replace all these values (=, +, /) ?

Comment: Pay attention, replace 'str.Replace('-', '+')' and 'str.Replace('_', '/')' with 'str = str.Replace('-', '+')' and 'str = str.Replace('_', '/')'.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code is incorrect. For example  `str.Replace('-', '+')` does nothing. Why people does not test their code which they enters as answer to others?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Replace)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue

Answer (score 0):

Valid code for decoding from url safe base64. Binary tested against pdf file.

```
    byte[] UrlDecode(string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        {
            return null;
        }

        str = str.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
        int paddings = str.Length % 4;
        if (paddings > 0)
            str += new string('=', 4 - paddings);

        byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(str);
        return encodedDataAsBytes;
    }
```