# Does UrlDecode handle plus (+) correctly?

Tags: .net, url-encoding

According to [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt),

> The plus "+", dollar "$", and comma
>   "," characters have been added to
>   those in the "reserved" set, since
>   they are treated as reserved    within
>   the query component.

Indeed, search this site for "plus + comma , dollar $", and you get

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=plus+%2B+comma+,+dollar+$

Plus is only encoded (by the application) when it's not being used as a delimiter.

But as [others have observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391057/urlencoding-plus-in-url-in-asp-net), .NET's `UrlDecode` function converts plus to space.  Where is this behavior specified?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Where is this behavior specified?

The [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) spec, curiously enough.

`UrlDecode` is kind of misleadingly named.

`+` only stands for a space in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data as defined by HTML; that is, either in a form POST submission request body or in the `?query` part of the URL. This is a special case! Elsewhere in the URL a plus is just a plus.

```
http://www.example.com/path+path/x?query+name=query+value
```

In this URL the parameter `query name` is set to `query value`. It might be generated by submitting this form field in a GET form:

```
<input name="query name" value="query value">
```

However, the folder name is literally `path+path`. No space.

Because this is confusing and potentially ambiguous, the best approach is always to encode spaces to `%20`. You can do that in .NET using [UrlPathEncode](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1). This works equally well in both the query part of the URL and the path.