# URL decode in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, urldecode

I am using Swift 1.2 to develop my iPhone application and I am communicating with a http web service.

The response I am getting is in query string format (key-value pairs) and URL encoded in `.Net`.

I can get the response, but looking the proper way to decode using Swift.

Sample response is as follows

```
status=1&message=The+transaction+for+GBP+12.50+was+successful
```

Tried following way to decode and get the server response

```
// This provides encoded response String
var responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
var decodedResponse = responseString.stringByReplacingEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

How can I replace all URL escaped characters in the string?

Comment: Best to update to Swift 2 now rather than later. And it really is better and easier to code in.

Comment: "replace `+` with `" "`, before use `stringByReplacingEscapesUsingEncoding` method" So what's the problem? Do that and see what happens.

Comment: @matt, Yes, I've done it and + gets replaced with Space. But wondering if any other special cases (Like +) can be there and will NOT read the exact thing the server sends

Comment: @zaph, Is there a way in SWIFT 2.0 ?

Answer (score 108):

To encode and decode urls create this extention somewhere in the project:

**Swift 2.0**

```
extension String
{   
    func encodeUrl() -> String
    {
        return self.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters( NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
    }
func decodeUrl() -> String
    {
        return self.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding
    }

}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
 extension String
    {   
        func encodeUrl() -> String
        {
            return self.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed())
        }
    func decodeUrl() -> String
        {
            return self.removingPercentEncoding
        }

    }
```

**Swift 4.1**

```
extension String
{
    func encodeUrl() -> String?
    {
        return self.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
    }
    func decodeUrl() -> String?
    {
        return self.removingPercentEncoding
    }
}
```

Comment: `addingPercentEncoding` and `removingPercentEncoding` return `Optional` strings so the return type should be `String?`.

Comment: Even simpler than the [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/WorkingwithURLEncoding/WorkingwithURLEncoding.html). Thanks.

Comment: This is very incorrect. The character set constants were not made to encode URL, and for that reason you cannot use any of the predefined sets to encode URL. You would have to create a new one. Your code won't encode `&` and `=` correctly, for example. Decoding will work though.

Comment: decoding string by removingPercentEncoding after that string converted %5Cn to \n but not working \n in UILabel and Hard code string \n is working in UIlabel showing by new line but decoded string not working.
can you please help me to give suggestion for this?

Answer (score 9):

Swift 2 and later (Xcode 7)

```
var s = "aa bb -[:/?&=;+!@#$()',*]";

let sEncode = s.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

let sDecode = sEncode?.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding
```

Answer (score 9):

You only need:

```
print("Decode: ", yourUrlAsString.removingPercentEncoding)
```

Answer (score 7):

The `stringByReplacingEscapesUsingEncoding` method is behaving correctly. The `"+"` character is *not part of percent-encoding*. This server is using it incorrectly; it should be using a percent-escaped space here (`%20`). If, for a particular response, you want spaces where you see `"+"` characters, you just have to work around the server behavior by performing the substitution yourself, as you are already doing.

Comment: And see this answer to understand what the `+` is really for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2700981/341994

Comment: Hi matt, yes I know the server use + instead of %20 to represent space in the response (encoded query string response)... Java handles this situation and decode properly "URLDecoder.decode(responseString, "UTF-8");"... I have added my temporary way made it working under edits in my question, but looking if there is any straight forward language API method available to decode properly rather than me replacing + with space before perform stringByReplacingEscapesUsingEncoding... Are you saying if that type of method NOT available in SWIFT?

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use built-in `URLComponents` struct, since it follows proper guidelines.

```
extension URL
{
    var parameters: [String: String?]?
    {
        if  let components = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false), 
            let queryItems = components.queryItems
        {
            var parameters = [String: String?]()
            for item in queryItems {
                parameters[item.name] = item.value
            }
            return parameters
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I NEED a plus ("+") signal in a phone number in parameters of a query string, like "+55 11 99999-5555". After I discovered that the swift3 (xcode 8.2) encoder don't encode "+" as plus signal, but space, I had to appeal to a workaround ***after the encode***:

**Swift 3.0**

```
_strURL = _strURL.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2B")
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3**

```
extension URL {
    var parseQueryString: [String: String] {
        var results = [String: String]()

        if let pairs = self.query?.components(separatedBy: "&"),  pairs.count > 0 {
            for pair: String in pairs {
                if let keyValue = pair.components(separatedBy: "=") as [String]? {
                    results.updateValue(keyValue[1], forKey: keyValue[0])
                }
            }
        }
        return results
    }
}
```

in your code to access below

```
let parse = url.parseQueryString
        print("parse \(parse)" )
```