# Why does Request.QueryString["path"] converts all + signs to spaces?

Tags: c#, asp.net, request, query-string, sign

I have a javascript code like this :

```
function OnRequestComplete(result) {
        // Download the file
        //Tell browser to open file directly
        alert(result);
        var requestImage = "Handler.ashx?path=" + result;
        document.location = requestImage;
}
```

and Handler.ashx code is like this :

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    Context = context;
    string filePath = context.Request.QueryString["path"];
    filePath = context.Server.MapPath(filePath);
}
```

In filePath we don't have any + signs (spaces instead).
How can I solve this issue ?
Why does Request.QueryString["path"] converts all + signs to spaces ?

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123994/querystring-malformed-after-urldecode/124027#124027

Comment: Querystrings have their own syntax and reserved chars. Encode you filename yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you correctly encode the query string a space becomes `+` and `+` becomes `%2B`. The process of decoding does the reverse, which is why your `+` gets turned into a space.

The problem is that you didn't [encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object) the query string, and that means it gets decoded incorrectly.

```
var requestImage = "Handler.ashx?path=" + encodeURIComponent(result);
```

Comment: thanks for answer / should i encode that query string in javascript? how?